# Using NSWorkspace selectFile:inFileViewerRootedAtPath: with files on the desktop

Tags: cocoa, selection, finder

You can do something like this to have the finder open a window and select a file:

```
[[NSWorkspace sharedWorkspace] selectFile:file inFileViewerRootedAtPath:root]
```

This is fine for most files, but as far as I can work out, if the file is on the desktop, the Finder will still open a viewer window for it, even if you pass the path to the desktop as the root.

Has anyone worked out a way to get the Finder to simply select the file on the desktop?

Is there something sneaky that one can pass as root to convince the Finder to do the sensible thing?

I imagine that I could write an applescript to do what I want, but I can't help feeling that there ought to be an easier way...

Comment: I don't know if it is the sensible thing. Most of the time the actual desktop is covered with app windows and the desktop can't be "brought to the front", so highlighting an icon on the desktop would be counter-intuitive.

Comment: Yep, I implemented a solution that used applescript to talk the Finder, and I agree that in practise it's not necessarily a very useful thing to do!